# Static methods declared but not defined error c++

Tags: c++

I have a static method in class as follows in file **Convert.h**

```
class Convert
{
    public :
    static string convertIntToStr(unsigned int integer);    
};
```

In **Convert.cpp**

```
string 
Convert::convertIntToStr(unsigned int integer) 
{
    ostringstream ostr;
    ostr <<  integer;
    return ostr.str();
}
```

I use this in some other class method in another .cpp file as `Convert::convertIntToStr`, but I get linking error, which says undefined reference to `Convert::convertIntToStr(unsigned int)`. Could you please let me know what could be wrong?

Comment: Because you don't link with the object file that the function is defined in?

Comment: And do not use `using namespace std` in a real code. (I am sorry if I am wrong and you have omitted `std::` prefix for `string` and `ostringstream` just for the sake of this example.)

Comment: Please show your compiler invocation.  If using an IDE, is Convert.cpp in the list of stuff to compile *and link*?

Comment: @АнтонЕлькин: He also might have explicit `using std::string;` and `using std::ostringstream;` declarations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

With multiple cpp file, you have to link the compiled object file into executable. In IDE like eclipse CDT or Visual stdio, It has been done for you.

To compile and link by yourself, with gcc for example, write `Makefile`:

```
CC=g++
CPPFLAGS=-fPIC -Wall -g -O2
all:executable

executable: convert.o other.o 
    $(CC)  $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^

convert.o: convert.cpp
    $(RC) $^

other.o: other.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^



.PHONY:clean

clean:
    rm *.o executable
```